# iptables port forwarding for active UDP connections

Tags: linux, networking, udp, iptables, port-forwarding

I am trying to set up port forwarding on UDP from `port 12345` to `port 54321` using the following:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i eth0 -d 192.168.0.1  --dport 12345 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:54321

iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -i eth0 -d 192.168.0.1 --dport 54321 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

This works fine for new connections, however, it wouldn't work for connections currently active.

To clarify what I mean, let's say that before adding the rules, there is an active connection from `192.168.0.2:55555` <---> `192.168.0.1:12345`, and I am trying to redirect all incoming connections on `192.168.0.1:12345` to `192.168.0.1:54321`.

After adding the above two rules, all other packets destined to `192.168.0.1:12345` are received at `192.168.0.1:54321` except the ones from `192.168.0.2:55555`.

I guess the state of the connection plays a role in this. How can I solve this and get the packets from `192.168.0.1:55555` destined to `port 12345` get delivered to `port 54321`?

Comment: UDP are datagram packets, there's no sense of "active connection" like with TCP. Or are you talking about some higher layer protocol handshake?

Comment: I explained the case! I know UDP is connectionless, but after I add the port forwarding rules, packets from a previously seen remote IP and Port are not forwarded to the new port.

Comment: anyone has any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it!

You need to use the REDIRECT on NAT! However before that you have to erase the entry corresponding to this connection from conntrack! Something like the following

```
conntrack -D -p udp -d  192.168.0.1 --dport=55555
```